# "Error: imported content is empty" when using =IMPORTXML() for a feed

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

If I input `=IMPORTXML("http://dilbert.com/feed")` I get all the feed content, but when I input `=IMPORTXML("http://dilbert.com/feed","//updated")`
I get `#N/A`: `Error: imported content is empty`.

Which XPath have I to use to return only the set of `<updated>` entries field?

P.S.: I don't want to use `=IMPORTFEED()` because it can return only some predefined feed item fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? `http://dilbert.com/feed` is in a cell "A1".

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name()='updated']")
```

#### Result :

[image]

#### Reference :

- https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name()='entry']//*[local-name()='updated']")
```

Comment: Great! But how can I avoid getting the first one? That is, how can I get only ones under <entry> tags and not the one under <feed> tag?

Comment: @tic I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. Is my understanding for your comment correct? If I misunderstand it, please tell me.